# Passing arguments to MATLAB script/function

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I'm trying to pass arguments to my MATLAB script via this command in a Terminal running Bash:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "K18 1 20 'file.csv'"  -logfile log.log
```

The K18.m file looks like this:

```
function K18(param1, param2)
   disp(param2); % displays 2,0 not the scalar 20
end
```

However, as you see I pass as a second param (param2) a number, i.e. 20.
When my MATLAB script executes, param2 is however a vector.
I searched the MATLAB central questions on how to pass parameters, and this seems the correct way... Strangely my scalar 20 is converted to a vector 2,0.

Here is a post on SO how to pass arguments to a MATLAB function via CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981168/running-a-matlab-program-with-arguments

This is MATLAB R2017a (9.2.0.556344) 64-bit (glnxa64) on a Linux system.

Hope this question fits this forum.

Regards!

Comment: I don’t understand what this question is about.   (1) You talk about a bash script. Is there something that works from the bash command line but not from a script? If so, please show what works and what doesn’t. If you *can’t* get it to work correctly from the command line, focus on that.  (2) You say “param2 will be a vector: 2,0 in my MATLAB script.” I don’t want to be pedantic, but are you saying that, when you run the bash script you show, your MATLAB script gets param2 with a vector value? Have you tried varying the parameters in the shell script and looking for a pattern in what you get?

Comment: Thank you Scott. I tried to clarify my question. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, that’s clearer; thank you. Unfortunately, I don’t know MATLAB, so I won’t be able to answer your question, but maybe now somebody else can.

Comment: Yes I will add also the MATLAB central links.